# Ubuntu 22.04 proprietry nvidia-driver-470 GK106 [GeForce GTX 660] using nvidia-prime Not working

Tags: 22.04, wayland, nvidia-prime, dkms, oem

I got this old nvidia card and decided to install it in my son's PC.
It's been a while since I had to use the propriety drivers, so It's a bit confusing to me. It would be great if someone can help verify my setup is correct, as I don't seem to be able to run glxgears on the nvidia card.

What I have:

- Dell Vostro 3910
- 12th Gen Intel Core™ i3-12100
- Nvidia card GK106 [GeForce GTX 660]

Main issues:

1- cannot (don't know how to) use the dGPU. I tried

```
$ __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia glxgears -info
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  26
  Current serial number in output stream:  27
```

2- Nvidia-settings did not show the card and only allows setting the prime profiles.
I set it to `performance` and still the same result.
This is what it shows on the commandline:

```
$ sudo nvidia-settings 

(nvidia-settings:9650): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 18:19:34.710: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

** (nvidia-settings:9650): CRITICAL **: 18:19:34.710: ctk_powermode_new: assertion '(ctrl_target != NULL) && (ctrl_target->h != NULL)' failed

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file or the X server is not accessible. This file should have been installed along with this driver at
       /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help
       text. Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.

** Message: 18:19:34.727: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: 18:19:34.727: PRIME: is it supported? yes
** Message: 18:19:34.746: PRIME: Usage: /usr/bin/prime-select nvidia|intel|on-demand|query
** Message: 18:19:34.746: PRIME: on-demand mode: "1"
** Message: 18:19:34.746: PRIME: is "on-demand" mode supported? yes
```

3- If someone could explain the various prime-* and nvidia-* commands as I couldn't find any proper help/documentation. In particular, what is `prime-switch` and how it is different than `prime-select`? what is `prime-offloading`? there is no `prime-select` command installed! any pointers are much appreciated.

What I did so far:

- Installed the distro provided drivers using `sudo ubuntu-drivers install`
- updated to latest firmware
- switched to Wayland (tried with X11 as well but still not working)
- purged the nvidia drivers and installed the oem kernel 6.5.0-1009-oem (was on the default 6.2 and the same result as well) and now using `dkms`.
- selected the nvidia card from BIOS as primary, and tried to use the card's HDMI slot and got no signal. The iGPU HDMI however is still works

thanks again